# Smart data structure in C++ to save data for faster access

Tags: c++, stl

I have a set of objects that each contain a value. The simplified version is as follows:

```
struct Object
{
   int value;
   ...
};
```

The value may change during some operations. It is possible for different `Object`s to have the same value.

Now I need to save these data in a container so that I can have fast access to the objects with the maximal, 2nd maximal, minimal, 2nd minimal values. Since the values can change during some operations, I hope the update will not be very expensive.

The number of `Object`s is decided. The only thing one will change is the value inside each object.

Is it possible to have some good data structure for this case?

I've tried to use `set`/`multiset` with value as key, but it does not behave very well since a lot of objects may have the same value.

Comment: Sounds like you need a heap

Comment: That's a really bad name for a struct

Comment: What do you mean with "_does not behave very well_"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [**min-max heap**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap), which is like a min or max heap, but odd rows are min's of their children and even rows are max's of their children.

You can get the second-smallest or second-largest by looking at the children of min or max nodes, which can be found in constant time because they're right there at the top of the heap.

You'll have to implement it yourself; I did it myself a few weeks ago, it's not that bad.

Comment: This sounds like to be what I want... thx

Answer (score 1):

You can use two binary heaps to keep the elements sorted in ascending and descending order. The first element in each heap is then the min/max of all values. You can get the second smallest/largest values by comparing the two children of the root of each heap. So access to the smallest/largest elements will be O(1).

You can insert/remove/update values in a binary heap in O(log n). However, since you need to update the values, you'll need to implement the siftUp/siftDown functions yourself, because the `std::push_heap` and `std::pop_heap` functions do not suffice.

You should use a `std::vector` to store the elements inside your heap class, especially since the total number of elements is fixed.

The downside of this approach is that you need to store the data twice. If your objects are large, you could build two heaps of pointers to the real elements instead to save some overhead. But if you need to store `int`s that won't help.

**Edit:**
A min-max heap would prevent the double storage. See [Mehrdad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24333531/1741297).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might use a [priority queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/), a concept similar to heaps.

Just implement the comparison object yourself and you'll be good to go. You can have duplicate values as well, but note that it won't be a **stable** algorithm with respect to equal elements, so don't rely on that.

Also notice that this is an adaptor. You might want to experiment with different containers to see if they suit your requirements (what are your complexity requirements?)

Comment: for priority queue, the max element can be get very faster. But how about the 2nd max, min and 2nd min? BTW, I hope to have O(1) access, and log(N) for update

Comment: Since you need to re-evaluate the children, you can pop the values off and get the new "top". Those are guaranteed with a heap, make sure to pick the right container though (by default it's a vector, heaps use arrays internally to do the sink-down swim-up mechanics).

Comment: If I use vector as a container, is it good for update? I mean when the value of an object changes, how to maintain the order? thx

Comment: The vector is the default and it would surely be a good choice. I can't assure it would be the fastest, but I'd start with that and see if it suits my needs.

Comment: @user1875680: you should edit the complexity requirements in your question.

Comment: Whenever I've needed a priority queue, I've found that the interface of `std::priority_queue` is too limited, because I need to update values in the queue, or iterate over all values, or I need to be able to clear the queue. I think it's a rather useless class.

Answer (score 0):

How about a [double-ended queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) (`std::deque`)?

You will have fast access to the highest value and the lowest value and `std::sort` can re-assert the correct order if you need. The only thing is that it won't "self-sort" when you update. However if you are clever about it you can minimise your need to re-sort until you modify the order of one your "special cases".

The problem with `priority queue` is that you would need to have one for the max values and one for the min values. Even then you would not have access to the 2nd from top values without popping the top value first. Your case is quite specialised so perhaps wrapping a `deque` would be the best solution for you.

Comment: Why a `deque` rather than a `vector` given that the number of objects is constant ?

Comment: Sorry I hadn't noticed that stipulation. In that case yeah, a vector.